# Does javascript work on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, mobile-phones

Does javascript work on mobile phones?

Comment: You may want to add to the question, as this is too general to really be answered.

Comment: In gerneal terms yes. For more specific answer go to superuser.com

Comment: @James, you are right that this is too general to be answered with any really useful information. However, there is a correct answer to this question: "Yes"

Comment: This is not a superuser question. This is useful to any web developer concerned about mobile phone support.

Comment: @A. Levy: I think the actual correct answer is "maybe".

Comment: The correct answer is "It depends what you mean by 'JavaScript', and by 'work'". For example, some phones support JavaScript but don't implement important DOM methods, meaning scripts written for a different phone won't work on them. And lots of phones don't support JS anyway. ppk is doing a lot of testing in this area; his recent results prove that even among the subset of phones that use WebKit, there is no consistency in either DOM or CSS support: http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

Comment: @NickFitz: do you read answers much? Two people already linked to that table.

Comment: Not on my phone - it struggles to make a call. BTW - Accept a few answers - It would be nice to do that.

Answer (score 40):

Which mobile phones?

There's some pretty good information on this site:

http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Answer (score 8):

depends on the browser

Answer (score 4):

*Some.*  Do you have a specific model in mind or just in general?

Comment: in general,I'm developing a mobi site, so the best solution to the problem i have is javasript.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what mobile phones and to what extent you need support.

Smart phones pretty much all include support for JavaScript. How **well** they support them is another story.

You can see a lot of what mobile devices support here: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Answer (score 2):

In general I would assume that javascript isn't there, as older cellphone models may not support javascript, but, if you use unobtrusive javascript and graceful degradation, then it won't really matter, as your page will function in some known way on any device, as long as it is formatting itself properly.

So, if you want to have it work on all mobile phones, then start with not needing javascript, then add in the javascript as an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Bare in mind as well that their are different versions of JavaScript supported by different phones and different browsers, even if JavaScript is available.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.skyfire.com/ if you can get that browser on it then you can get javascript! Awesome browser and quite portable...

Works on Symbian (Nokia Phones use it) and Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript is totally browser dependent. Symbian mobile surely can run javascript. [Smart phones are much smarter](http://cellsindex.com/mobile-blackberry-m17) to handle javascript.