# Should we use server-side solution in place of javascript as much as possible for multi-device viewing?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

By multi-device viewing, I mean that it will be seen on both desktop computers and mobile.

Will mobile user get better performance and usability without JavaScript? Would it be good if we make site with pure CSS and server side programming for mobile? Opera Mini, iPhone safari, blackberry browser, Windows mobile browser, whatever?

Graceful degradation takes time to implement. So if we go with pure CSS for fancy things and server side solution for dynamic things , is it a better idea?

Although there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538004/does-javascript-work-on-mobile-phones/1538029#1538029), first think on pure CSS solution or server side solution if needed is a good idea I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone/browser combos you've mentioned all have fully functional javascript interpreters. Any modern smartphone is going to be capable of most of what you can throw at it. If you're doing excessive processing client side in javascript, you're probably doing it wrong already.

Write code that degrades gracefully, and if you're doing it right, your site should work properly without javascript by simply adhering to the standards. Start with a design that works without scripting, and then layer in the niceties. In most cases, this produces a cleaner, more maintainable application.

Comment: ok so we should go for server side solution first if available

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a ton about designing sites for mobile phones, but what you're saying sounds logical. JavaScript is run client-side, and since mobile devices have rather limited processors, it makes sense to do as much work as possible on the server.

Comment: @Mark - yes same thing i'm thinking

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it server side. You can use WURFL to get database of existing mobile devices and when you detect one you server a customized view for mobile devices.